# Livewire Select2 stop re render on change

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am working on a form with `select2` on it. The idea is that when user selects or changes any value in `select2` dropdown, need to run a method on selected `accountId`.

Display some message based on the selected `accountId` on the component. `blade.php` file is as following

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-12">
    <div wire:ignore>
        <select id="accountId" class="form-control" wire:model="accountId">
            @foreach($accounts as $index => $account)
                <option value="{{$index}}">{{ $account }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>                             
</div>
```

Following is the script to initiate `select2`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#accountId').select2().on('change', function (e) {
                    let data = $(this).val();
                    @this.set('accountId', data);
                });
});
```

How do I capture that data in my `Livewire` component and run necessary method on that `accountId`.

```
public function updatedAccountId($accountId)
{
    if ($accountId) {
        $account = Account::findOrFail($accountId);
        $this->accountAlert = 'some message for user to display';
    }
    else {
        $this->accountAlert = '';
    }
}
```

Method is called when `select2` data is changed but `select2` is not re-rendered.

How can I stop re-rendering of `select2` or re-render `select2` method?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Livewire.hook like:

[image]

Maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDXesGtMujU&t=10s) help you (portuguese).